# Scala Parser Combinators tricks for recursive bnf?

Tags: scala, ebnf, parser-combinators

Im trying to match this syntax:

```
pgm ::= exprs
exprs ::= expr [; exprs]
expr ::= ID | expr . [0-9]+
```

My scala packrat parser combinator looks like this:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._

object Dotter extends StandardTokenParsers with PackratParsers {
    lexical.delimiters ++= List(".",";")
    def pgm = repsep(expr,";")
    def expr :Parser[Any]= ident | expr~"."~num
    def num = numericLit

       def parse(input: String) =
    phrase(pgm)(new PackratReader(new lexical.Scanner(input))) match {
      case Success(result, _) => println("Success!"); Some(result)
      case n @ _ => println(n);println("bla"); None
    }  

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val prg = "x.1.2.3;" +
            "y.4.1.1;" +
            "z;" +
            "n.1.10.30"


            parse(prg);
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work. Either it "matches greedy" and tells me:

```
[1.2] failure: end of input expected 
x.1.2.3;y.4.1.1;z;n.1.10.30
```

or if I change the `|` to a `|||` I get a stackoverflow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Character.isLetter(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Character.isLetter(Unknown Source)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.Lexical$$anonfun$letter$1.apply(Lexical.scala:32)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.Lexical$$anonfun$letter$1.apply(Lexical.scala:32)
...
```

I kindoff understand why I get the errors; what can I do to parse a syntax like the above? It doesnt seem that esoteric to me

EDIT:
Based on the paper referenced in http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Packrat-parser-guidance-td1956908.html 
I found out that my program didnt actually use the new packrat parser.

Ie. change `Parser[Any]` to `PackratParser[Any]` and use `lazy val` instead of `def`

I rewrote the above to this:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._

object Dotter extends StandardTokenParsers with PackratParsers {
    lexical.delimiters ++= List(".",";")
    lazy val pgm : PackratParser[Any] = repsep(expr,";")
    lazy val expr :PackratParser[Any]= expr~"."~num | ident
    lazy val num = numericLit

    def parse(input: String) =
    phrase(pgm)(new PackratReader(new lexical.Scanner(input))) match {
      case Success(result, _) => println("Success!"); Some(result)
      case n @ _ => println(n);println("bla"); None
    }  

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val prg = "x.1.2.3 ;" +
            "y.4.1.1;" +
            "z;" +
            "n.1.10.30"


            parse(prg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is (at least partially) that you're not actually using Packrat parsers. See the documentation for Scala's [PackratParsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/PackratParsers.html) trait, which says

> Using PackratParsers is very similar
>   to using Parsers:
>
> - any class/trait that extends Parsers (directly or through a
>     subclass) can mix in PackratParsers.
>     Example: object MyGrammar extends
>     StandardTokenParsers with
>     PackratParsers
> - each grammar production previously declared as a def without
>     formal parameters becomes a lazy val,
>     and its type is changed from
>     Parser[Elem] to PackratParser[Elem].
>     So, for example, def production:
>     Parser[Int] = {...} becomes lazy val
>     production: PackratParser[Int] = {...}
> - Important: using PackratParsers is not an all or nothing decision.
>     They can be free mixed with regular
>     Parsers in a single grammar.

I don't know enough about Scala 2.8's parser combinators to fix this entirely, but with the following modifications, I was able to get it to parse as far as the semicolon, which is an improvement over what you've accomplished.

```
object Dotter extends StandardTokenParsers with PackratParsers {
    lexical.delimiters ++= List(".",";")
    lazy val pgm:PackratParser[Any] = repsep(expr,";")
    lazy val expr:PackratParser[Any]= ident ||| (expr~"."~numericLit)

    def parse(input: String) = phrase(expr)(lex(input)) match {
      case Success(result, _) => println("Success!"); Some(result)
      case n @ _ => println(n);println("bla"); None
    }  

    def lex(input:String) = new PackratReader(new lexical.Scanner(input))
}
```

Comment: Exactly! I was rereading documentation and figured this out. The last thing needed is a typo in the parse method: `phrase(expr)` should be `phrase(pgm)`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The production

```
expr ::= ID | expr . [0-9]+
```

is left recursive. It expands to

```
expr ::= ID
expr ::= expr . [0-9]+
```

where the left recursion occurs on the 2nd line. This is what causes the parser to overflow the stack.

You should rewrite your grammar avoiding left recursive productions.

```
expr ::= ID {. [0-9]+}
```

Comment: Wasnt the packrat parser supposed to allow me to do left-recursion?