# Scala PackratParsers: backtracking seems not to work

Tags: scala, backtracking, parser-combinators

The following scala code fails to work as expected:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StandardTokenParsers
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical.StdLexical

object Minimal extends StandardTokenParsers with PackratParsers {
  override val lexical = new StdLexical

  lexical.delimiters += ("<", "(", ")")

  lazy val expression: PackratParser[Any] = (
  numericLit
  | numericLit ~ "<" ~ numericLit
  )

  def parseAll[T](p: PackratParser[T], in: String): ParseResult[T] =
    phrase(p)(new PackratReader(new lexical.Scanner(in)))

  def main(args: Array[String]) = println(parseAll(expression, "2 < 4"))
}
```

I get the error message:

```
[1.3] failure: end of input expected

2 < 4
  ^
```

If however I change the definition of "expression" to

```
  lazy val expression: PackratParser[Any] = (
    numericLit ~ "<" ~ numericLit
  | numericLit
  )
```

the problem disappears.

The problem seems to be that with the original definition code for "expression" the first rule consisting only of "numericLit" is applied, such that the parser indeed expects the input to end immediately afterwards. I do not understand why the parser does not backtrack as soon as it notices that the input does not indeed end; scala PackratParsers are supposed to be backtracking, and I also made sure to replace "def" by "lazy val" as suggested in the answer to another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behaviour is that the alternation operator (vertical bar) is designed to accept the first of its alternatives that succeeds. In your case `numericLit` succeeds so the alternation never considers other alternatives.

With this kind of grammar specification you have to be careful if one alternative can match a prefix of another. As you've seen, the longer alternative should be placed earlier in the alternatives, otherwise it can never succeed.

If you wish the shorter alternative to match only if there is no more input after it, then you could try using the `not` combinator to express that extra condition. However, this approach will cause problems if `expression` is intended to be used inside other constructs.

Comment: One can also pick the longest match automatically with the triple bar choice operator, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3344646/53974.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with packrat parser.

What you need to know is that in [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar#Operational_interpretation_of_parsing_expressions), the choice operator selects the first match, which is `numericLit` in your case.